# Ajax Content Loading(Processing) image or indicator

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

in part of my web page, I have couple of asp:image Thumbnails, onclick I use ajax modal popup extender to show the imgae in full size which are working fine, what I need to add is to have a processing image or indicator both in thumbnail and modal popup extender,

I also have ajax autocomplete that is working fine, I need to add some indicator or processing image to it as soon as user start typing a word.

any idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Set the animation to visible while waiting for a callback

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [update progress control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updateprogress.aspx) to display a progress template within your update panel. It displays the contents of the ProgressTemplate tag whenever a postback occurs:

```
<asp:UpdateProgress runat="server" id="UpdateProgress" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="SomePanel" >
    <ProgressTemplate>
        <img src="processing.gif" alt="Processing" />
    </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
```

Also, I've found [Preloaders](http://preloaders.net) useful as a source of animated GIFs for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Look at http://www.ajaxload.info/. There are a ton of images there. Once the user types in some letters, however many you need, then display the ajax loader gif next to the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want the loader/indicator within control, so, one way could be to subclass the `PopupExtender` control, add `asp:UpdateProgress`, and put a loader.img in there.